# Как лучше писать бек-энд для мобильного приложения и стоит ли использовать Firebase на продакшине мобильного приложения?

Tags: android, node.js, ios, firebase, flutter

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос собственно в сабже, но дополню деталями.

Имеем Flutter, хотим "навелосипедить" небольшое мобильное приложение с реал-таймом, типа соц.сети.

Сколько гуглю, все время попадается связка Flutter + Firebase, как я понял - Firebase мне может помочь с реал-таймом, т.к. это есть из коробки, также имеются push-уведомления, аналитика и т.д.

И здесь у меня в голове встает несколько вопросов:

**1**. Хороша ли практика использования Firebase в продакшине и сильно ли это лупасит по карману? Ожидается, что будет очень частое обновление данных в БД и очень много коннектов, т.к. приложение специфичное и завязано на ГЕО-данных, которые постоянно сканируются и обновляются.

**2**. Как можно организовать Live-стрим видео в связке Flutter + Firebase? (если такое вообще возможно или это полный треш?)

**3**. Если Firebase летит в топку, то как лучше запилить бек-энд для моей задачи? Нужен реал-тайм чат 1 на 1, стримминг видео (аля инстаграмм эфир), ну и постоянное реалтаймовое обновление данных о ГЕО - была мысль взять за основу Node.js + MongoDB (или MySQL), но как тогда работать с PUSH-уведомлениями, которые нужно отправить по событию, хз.

Буду очень сильно благодарен, если подскажите возможные пути реализации и поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Firebase не берите для хранения данных. Судя по вашему описанию - разоритесь. И это без того, что аццки намучаетесь с ним (т.к. NoSQL). Пуши же без него не получится сделать - тут гугл всех конкурентов задавил.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Благодарю за ответ. Значит буду организовывать бек-энд на связке Node.JS + MongoDB (или может MySQL) + Socket.io, а пуши и аналитику брать у Firebase.

Comment: Погуглил хорошенько, почитал статьи и понял, что лучше Node.JS + MongoDB не кидать в бек-энд, т.к. слабая типизация кода, погуглил множество сервисов, везде мелькает Python + PostgreSQL.

Comment: Лучше уж тогда Postgres+Spring